# Javascript this points to Window object

Tags: javascript, this

I have the following code. I expected to see "archive" object on my firebug console, but I see Window object. Is it normal?

```
var archive = function(){}

archive.prototype.action = {
    test: function(callback){
        callback();
    },
    test2: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

var oArchive = new archive();
oArchive.action.test(oArchive.action.test2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`oArchive.action.test2` gets you a reference to a function that `callback` then points to, but that function is then called using `callback()`, which means it is not called as a method and hence `this` is the global object. The key point is that `this` is not bound to a function: it's determined by how the function is called.

In this case you could explicitly make `this` point to the action object (but not the archive object) by using the callback function's `call` or `apply` method:

```
test: function(callback) {
    callback.call(this);
},
```

To get it `this` to be the archive object instead, you'll need to pass the archive object in:

```
var archive = function(){}

archive.prototype.action = {
    test: function(callback, archive){
        callback.call(archive);
    },
    test2: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

var oArchive = new archive();
oArchive.action.test(oArchive.action.test2, oArchive);
```