# javascript "this" points to Window object again

Tags: javascript, reference, function-call

I asked a question on [Javascript this points to Window object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719643/javascript-this-points-to-window-object) regarding "this" points to Window object.

here is source code

```
var archive = function(){} 

archive.prototype.action = { 
    test: function(callback){ 
        callback(); 
    }, 
    test2: function(){ 
        console.log(this); 
    } 
} 

var oArchive = new archive(); 
oArchive.action.test(oArchive.action.test2);
```

Tim Down wrote "but that function is then called using callback(), which means it is not called as a method and hence this is the global object".

What are differences between calling a function by its actual name and callback() as shown on the source code?

How does console.log(this) in test2 points to Window when it is inside archive.action???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In JavaScript you can invoke functions using 4 different invocation patterns:

- Function invocation
- Method invocation
- Apply/Call invocation
- Construction invocation

The patterns mainly differ in how the `this` parameter is initialized.

When you use `oArchive.action.test2()`, you would be invoking the `test2()` function with the method pattern, and in this case `this` would be bound to the `action` object. JavaScript will use the method pattern whenever the invocation expression contains a refinement (i.e. the `.` dot expression or the `[subscript]` expression).

On the other hand, when a function is not the property of an object, then it is invoked using the function pattern. In this case, the `this` parameter is bound to the global object, and in fact this is how JavaScript is invoking your `callback()` function.

[Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) in his [Good Parts book](http://books.google.com/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=javascript+good+parts&source=bl&ots=HHsim6s_lE&sig=7rtiJx1lseFxls-T2Sh9h-OLh0E&hl=en&ei=okXES-_KA5n40wSWof3PDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CCgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), describes this as a mistake in the design of the language, and suggests some possible workarounds. In you case, one easy workaround would be to invoke the callback using `call()` or `apply()`, as [Tim Down suggested in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719643/javascript-this-points-to-window-object/2719696#2719696):

```
callback.call(this);
```

This works because the Apply/Call invocation pattern lets you choose the value of `this`, which is what you require.

Comment: I think you could also use oArchive.action.test2.bind(oArchive.action.test) when calling oArchive.action.test

Answer (score 4):

In javascript the `this` keyword is set to the owner of a function. Function objects do not maintain their ownership themselves, instead the ownership is deduced from the way we call a function.

eg:

```
var foo = function() {
    alert('hello');
};
var abc = {};
abc.bar = foo;
```

Simply calling the function like

```
foo();
```

gives the interpreter no clue about what object the function might be attached to. It may be attached to multiple objects, it may be a variable etc. So the interpreter sets `this` to the global object.

But however, when calling a function like

```
abc.bar();
```

the interpreter knows that function is attached to `abc` object, therefore `this` is set to `abc`. Even if both `bar` and `foo` refer to the same function object, the difference in the calling pattern causes `this` to behave differently.