# "this" value in compute of Mobx 4 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobx

This is the first time I use Mobx and I'm trying to understand how it works to apply for my project (which is not React base, just use jquery to update the DOM).
I started with Mobx 4 (I need to support for old browsers so I don't use the latest version 6 ) and followed a example [here](https://stackoverflow.com) but it used Mobx 2 version.
When using with Mobx 4, it throws an error in this:

```
function ShoppingCart() {
    mobx.extendObservable(this, {
        entries: [],
        total: function() {
            return this.entries.reduce(function (sum, entry) {
                return sum + entry.price;
            }, 0);
        }

    });
}
```

The console says: `mobx] Encountered an uncaught exception that was thrown by a reaction or observer component, in: 'Reaction[Autorun@19]' TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')`

I tried to use the anonymous function like this:

```
function ShoppingCart() {
    mobx.extendObservable(this, {
        entries: [],
        total: () => {
            return this.entries.reduce(function (sum, entry) {
                return sum + entry.price;
            }, 0);
        }

    });
}
```

But it returned the function declaration like this: `0function () { return this.article ? this.article.price * this.amount : 0; }`

I wonder that what's the difference here? And how Mobx handle this(.entries) in this case?
Why this compute cannot get the value of entries? Thank you!

This is a link to project in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quangcanh2975/aL6qyzj5/4/):

Or entire of my source:

```
/** Data model */
function Article(name, price) {
    mobx.extendObservable(this, {
        name: name,
        price: price
    });
}

function ShoppingCartEntry(article) {
    mobx.extendObservable(this, {
        article: article,
        amount: 1,
        price: function () {
            return this.article ? this.article.price * this.amount : 0;
        }
    });
}

function ShoppingCart() {
    mobx.extendObservable(this, {
        entries: [],
        total: function () {
            return this.entries.reduce(function (sum, entry) {
                return sum + entry.price;
            }, 0);
        }

    });
}

$(function () {

// Some available articles
    var articles = mobx.observable([
        ["Funny Bunnies", 17.63],
        ["Awesome React", 23.95],
        ["Second hand netbook", 50.00]
    ].map(function (e) {
        return new Article(e[0], e[1]);
    }));

// Our shopping cart
    var shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
// With a demo item inside
    shoppingCart.entries.push(new ShoppingCartEntry(articles[0]));

    $.fn.insertAt = function (index, $parent) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (index === 0) {
                $parent.prepend(this);
            } else {
                $parent.children().eq(index - 1).after(this);
            }
        });
    };

    /** UI Logic */
    var $articles = $("#articles");

// Make the articles list follow the array
    articles.observe(function (change) {
        console.log(change);
        // items where added or removed
        if (change.type === "splice") {
            $articles.children().slice(change.index, change.index + change.removed.length).remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < change.addedCount; i++) {
                renderArticle(articles[change.index + i])
                    .insertAt(change.index + i, $articles);
            }
        }
    }, true); // true makes sure the observe function is invoked immediately

// Render an article in the articles overview, and watch or changes
    function renderArticle(article) {
        var $name = $("<span>").text(article.name);
        var $price = $("<span>").addClass("price").text(article.price);
        mobx.autorun(function () {
            $name.text(article.name);
        });
        mobx.autorun(function () {
            $price.text(article.price);
        });
        return $("<li>").append($name,
            $("<button>").text("+").addClass("add-article"),
            $("<button>").text("edit").addClass("edit-article"),
            $price);
    }

// ShoppingCart ui
    var $cart = $("#cart");
    var $total = $("#total");

    mobx.autorun(function () {
        // console.log(shoppingCart, shoppingCart.total, shoppingCart.entries);
        $total.text(shoppingCart.total);
    }, true);

    shoppingCart.entries.observe(function (change) {
        // items where added or removed
        if (change.type === "splice") {
            $cart.children().slice(change.index, change.index + change.removed.length).remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < change.addedCount; i++) {
                renderCartEntry(shoppingCart.entries[change.index + i])
                    .insertAt(change.index + i, $cart);
            }
        }
    }, true);

    function renderCartEntry(entry) {
        var $name = $("<span>").text(entry.article.name);
        var $amount = $("<span>").addClass("price").text(entry.amount);
        mobx.autorun(function () {
            $name.text(entry.article.name);
        });
        mobx.autorun(function () {
            $amount.text(entry.amount);
        });
        return $("<li>").append(
            $("<button>").text("-").addClass("remove-article"),
            $name,
            $amount);
    }


// Events
    $("#new-article").on("click", function () {
        articles.push(new Article(prompt("Article name"), prompt("Price")));
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".edit-article", function (event) {
        var idx = $(event.target).parent().index();
        articles[idx].name = prompt("New name");
        articles[idx].price = prompt("New price");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".add-article", function (event) {
        var article = articles[$(event.target).parent().index()];
        var existingEntry = shoppingCart.entries.find(function (entry) {
            return entry.article === article;
        });
        if (existingEntry)
            existingEntry.amount += 1;
        else
            shoppingCart.entries.unshift(new ShoppingCartEntry(article));
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".remove-article", function (event) {
        var entryIndex = $(event.target).parent().index();
        if ((shoppingCart.entries[entryIndex].amount -= 1) < 1)
            shoppingCart.entries.splice(entryIndex, 1);
    });
})
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the word `this` is a reserved word, I would maybe try change it and see if it solves the problem

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen, thanks for your comment. I'm so confused which the version 4 and 2 are use the same syntax. But they're totally different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript "this" points to Window object again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752291/javascript-this-points-to-window-object-again)

Comment: In JavaScript `this` is whatever the current context is and often falls over when you expect `this` to be something that it isn't.

Comment: Hi @phuzi, the original one with Mobx 2 worked fine. I think Mobx does bind the right 'this' to the compute in this. But I'm glad to hear from your opinions who use Mobx before

Comment: I also tried to use anonymous function to bind the right this context. You can read in my question.

Comment: Thanks @phuzi, you're right about `this` value. I updated the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Like @phuzi's suggestion. This is all about `this` in JS. My mistake to accept Mobx usage example without doubting about `this` value. The right `ShoppingCartEntry` function should be like this:

```
function ShoppingCartEntry(article) {
    mobx.extendObservable(this, {
        article: article,
        amount: 1,
        price: () => {
            return this.article ? this.article.price * this.amount : 0;
        }
    });
}
```

I use the arrow function for price, so `this` will be `ShoppingCartEntry` now.
Then we need to update `ShoppingCart` to this:

```
function ShoppingCart() {
    mobx.extendObservable(this, {
        entries: [],
        total: () => {
            return this.entries.reduce(function (sum, entry) {
                return sum + entry.price();
            }, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Compare to the example of Mobx v2, `entry.price` has to call as a function.
Or we can update the `ShoppingCartEntry` like this to use the getter for price to let `entry.price` the same before:

```
class ShoppingCartEntry {
    article;

    constructor(article) {
        this.article = article;
        mobx.extendObservable(this, {
            article: article,
            amount: 1,
        });
    }

    get price() {
        return this.article ? this.article.price * this.amount : 0;
    }
}
```